# Configuration exception thrown when ServiceStack RegisterLicense method is called

Tags: servicestack

When invoking this method, `Licensing.RegisterLicense(licenseKey);`, I get a initialization exception with the following inner error:

> Message=Unrecognized configuration section DbProviderFactories. (C:\Actevis\Development\Actevis.Cloud\SqlLiteTestBed\bin\Debug\SqlLiteTestBed.vshost.exe.Config line 16)

Here is the offending config section:

```xml
<DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
    <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

I have tried adding an `appsetting` section to the app.config file but the same error still appears. Since the `DbProviderFactories` are not present in the app.config file I assume that the section is injected by ServiceStack.

I am trying to use `ServiceStack.Ormlite.SQLite32`. This is the nuget package that was installed.  I have copied the license file a few times to make sure that there was not problem there.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're Web.config is invalid and the error gets thrown when first trying to access the Web.config, which is what ServiceStack does when it looks for the **servicestack:license** app setting.

Note: the `<DbProviderFactories>` should be declared inside `<system.data>` tags:

```xml
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
    <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

This was caused by the Web.config.transforms in the dependent [System.Data.SQLite.x86](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.x86/) package. This could also be a bug in NuGet's web.config.transform as the rule says to add it under `<system.data>...</system.data>` but it's being added to the top-level creating an invalid Web.config configuration.

The entire config isn't needed for OrmLite so can be removed. I've also reached out to the SQLite maintainer to notify him about this issue so hopefully will be resolved in future issues.

Whilst I'm looking at making changes to OrmLite's Sqlite packages to embed the dlls and remove the dependency to the Sqlite packages that's causing this error.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your reply.  I was able to figure out what was happening:

When installing the ServiceStack.Ormlite.Sqlite32 package, Entity framework and EntityFramework for SQLServer is also installed.  There seems to be an issue when using Sqlite and EntryFramework for Sql Server together.  I deleted all the entity framework related DGG's from the project and removed the sections from the app.config file.  This has fixed the problem.

Comment: I've looked into this and it looks like it's an issue with the SQLite dependency package Web.config.transform. You can also remove the problematic `<DbProviderFactories>` section from the Web.config.